# How to create admin user in django tests.py

Tags: django, functional-testing

I'm trying to create an admin user as part of my tests.py to check on persmissions.

UPDATE:
The tests.py is standard format that subclasses TestCase and the code below is called in the setUp() function.

I can create a normal user but not an admin user.  If I try this:

```
    self.adminuser = User.objects.create_user('admin', 'admin@test.com', 'pass')
    self.adminuser.save()
    self.adminuser.is_staff = True
    self.adminuser.save()
```

OR
        self.adminuser = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@test.com', 'pass')
        self.adminuser.save()

I get:

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1
```

If I remove the is_staff line all is well (except I can't do my test!)

Do I have to load admin users as fixtures?

UserProfile is defined as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

and full error traceback is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/test/testcases.py", line 242, in __call__
        self._pre_setup()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/test/testcases.py", line 217, in _pre_setup
        self._fixture_setup()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/test/testcases.py", line 440, in _fixture_setup
        return super(TestCase, self)._fixture_setup()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/test/testcases.py", line 222, in _fixture_setup
        call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
        return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
        return self.handle_noargs(**options)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/flush.py", line 61, in handle_noargs
        emit_post_sync_signal(models.get_models(), verbosity, interactive)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/core/management/sql.py", line 205, in emit_post_sync_signal
        interactive=interactive)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 166, in send
        response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 28, in create_permissions
        defaults={'name': name, 'content_type': ctype})
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 123, in get_or_create
        return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 335, in get_or_create
        obj.save(force_insert=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 410, in save
        self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in save_base
        result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 177, in _insert
        return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in insert_query
        return query.execute_sql(return_id)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 320, in execute_sql
        cursor = super(InsertQuery, self).execute_sql(None)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 84, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in execute
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _warning_check
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/warnings.py", line 61, in warn
        warn_explicit(message, category, filename, lineno, module, registry)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/warnings.py", line 96, in warn_explicit
        raise message
    Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1
```

**The answer** seems to be that you can't create an admin user in setUp but you can in any other function so if you want an admin user in testing, use a fixture!

Comment: @phoebebright: can you post model code? Specifically, `UserProfile` and its relation to `User`.

Comment: @phoebebright: And do you have any fixtures setup?

Comment: @phoebebright:  On a side note, your `UserProfile` -> `User` reference should be a `OneToOneField`. See http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Comment: @phoebebright: are you calling this code snippet inside a `test_` method? Or `setUp`? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @phoebebright: I second Manoj's comment... How about just posting the test case class in it's entirety?

Comment: PROGRESS = if I move the command to create the user from setUp to one of the testcases it works fine!!!  So can't create an admin user in setUp I guess?

Comment: @sdolan Will fix the UserProfile = thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2**

Executed the snippet to create the superuser from within a test case (subclass of `django.test.TestCase`). Everything went fine. Also created and saved an instance of `UserProfile` with `user = self.adminuser`. That too worked.

**Update**

This line is interesting:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 28, in create_permissions
        defaults={'name': name, 'content_type': ctype})
```

Looks like execution fails when creating permissions.

**Original Answer**

> Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1

Strange. I tried this from the Django shell and it worked for me. I am using Postgresql 8.3 and Django 1.2.1 on Ubuntu Jaunty. Can you give more details about which version of Django/database are you using?

Also `User` does not have a `name` attribute. Can you double check if you are using `auth.User`?

> Do I have to load admin users as fixtures?

You don't *have to*. But if you are creating this admin user solely for testing purposes then it would be a good idea to add a Fixture. That is what I do in my projects.

Comment: Tried in shell and it works fine.  I have userprofile attached (that doesn't have name in it) and I can add userprofiles fine for other types of user, just not superuser or staff.  Baffled!

Comment: @phoebebright:  Does your error say what table it's occurring in... is it the auth_user table?

Comment: posted a bit more info above.

Answer (score 74):

I'd use the built-in [`create_superuser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L163) and log the user in before making any requests.  The following should work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test.client import Client

# store the password to login later
password = 'mypassword' 

my_admin = User.objects.create_superuser('myuser', 'myemail@test.com', password)

c = Client()

# You'll need to log him in before you can send requests through the client
c.login(username=my_admin.username, password=password)

# tests go here
```

Comment: still get the same error when I change create_user to create_superuser, without even trying to do the client bit...

Comment: Drop `c = Client()` and replace `c.login` with `self.client.login` when executed from within a test inheriting from `TestCase`